# Проблема с запуском Unity

Tags: unity3d

[image: Когда запускаю первый проект, выдаёт такую надпись:]
Что делать?
Я совсем новичок, юнити открыл впервые, ничего не понимаю.

Comment: У вас несовместимость версий. Вы Unity обновили? Или установили старую версию?

Comment: @Арман у меня последняя версия

Comment: Вы обновили `Unity`?